# Update data in one table from data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table `Customers` has 3 columns:

```
ID (primary)   city       country
1              Chicago    USA
2              Chicago    USA
3              New York   USA
4              Paris      France
```

And other table `locations` has 2 columns:

```
city (primary)       country
Chicago              Null (Empty)
New York             Null (Empty)
Paris                Null (Empty)
```

I created this `country` column in `locations` table to update `country` values from `Customers` table. Like:

```
UPDATE locations SET country = (SELECT country FROM customers);
```

But above query gives error: `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need UPDATE using JOIN syntax. Try this -

```
UPDATE locations L
JOIN Customers C ON C.city = L.city
SET L.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY;
```

Comment: Holy cow! it worked perfectly, I thought I have to manually edit 10k rows :)

Answer (score 0):

You were very close

```
UPDATE locations l 
SET 
    country = (SELECT 
            country
        FROM
            Customers
        WHERE
            city = l.city
        LIMIT 1)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE locations  (
>   `city` VARCHAR(25),
>   `country` VARCHAR(25)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO locations 
>   (`city`, `country`)
> VALUES
>   ('Chicago',              Null),
>   ('New York',             Null),
>   ('Paris',                Null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Customers  (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `city` VARCHAR(8),
>   `country` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Customers 
>   (`ID`, `city`, `country`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Chicago', 'USA'),
>   ('2', 'Chicago', 'USA'),
>   ('3', 'New York', 'USA'),
>   ('4', 'Paris', 'France');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>   <!-- -->
> CREATE TABLE locations  (
>   `city` VARCHAR(25),
>   `country` VARCHAR(25)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO locations 
>   (`city`, `country`)
> VALUES
>   ('Chicago',              Null),
>   ('New York',             Null),
>   ('Paris',                Null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Customers  (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `city` VARCHAR(8),
>   `country` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Customers 
>   (`ID`, `city`, `country`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Chicago', 'USA'),
>   ('2', 'Chicago', 'USA'),
>   ('3', 'New York', 'USA'),
>   ('4', 'Paris', 'France');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>   UPdate locations l SET country = (SELECT country FROM Customers WHERE city = l.city LIMIT 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * From locations;
> ```
>
> ```
> city     | country
> :------- | :------
> Chicago  | USA    
> New York | USA    
> Paris    | France
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a52b5f67e668598f3a03aa5d86c34fb)*

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * From locations;
> ```
>
> ```
> city     | country
> :------- | :------
> Chicago  | USA    
> New York | USA    
> Paris    | France
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a52b5f67e668598f3a03aa5d86c34fb)*